# Java: HTML in Swing, link margin not working

Tags: java, html, swing

Hi there 
I'm trying to format HTML content in Swing. Formattings such as color or text-decoration are working fine. But when it comes to margin of links it is not working at all.

This is all the CSS syntax I'm using:

```
StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
styleSheet.addRule("a {font : arial; text-decoration: none; color: #0174DF; margin-left: 50px}");
```

everything, except the `margin-left` is working. I tested the syntax in a Browser and it works fine there. I also tried using `text-align: left` or `display: block` becouse I found some articles pointing out that margin of links would not work without.

The following HTML code is used:

```
<html><head></head><body><div>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 50.24324324324324px">akamaitechnologies.com</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 17.37837837837838px">amazonaws.com</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 18.243243243243242px">cotendo.net</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 24.08108108108108px">facebook.com</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 17.594594594594597px">google.ch</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 55.0px">heise.de</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 16.08108108108108px">ip-plus.net</a>
<a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 21.054054054054056px">ligatus.com</a>
</div></body></html>
```

The HTML code is generated by a library and can't be modified.

From my understanding of HTML/CSS it is not possible to add `margin` style information to an inline object like a link becouse margin-top or margin-bottom is not possible. margin-left oder margin-right however should not be a problem.

thx

edit: by the way, I'm using HTMLEditorKit.

Comment: would padding-left work for you?

Comment: @ rob wrote 'The HTML code is generated by a library and can't be modified.' just info todays Java supported Html <= 3.2

Comment: @rob: `"font-size: 50.24324324324324px"`  You expect to control font size to within one 100 trillionth of a pixel?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: As I wrote, the html code is generated by a library I have no influence on that. But I thought the same as you when I saw the output.

@mKorbel: so margin style information is not supported in HTML 3.2? If so, is there a workaround to add some margin to the links in the code mentioned?

Comment: @Vincent: "would padding-left work for you?" +1  Works for me. ;)

Comment: @rob:  Why do *all* the HREFs point to `www.zhaw.ch`?  (Not really relevant to your question, it just has me curious.)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I abuse this library to generate the HTML code: http://opencloud.mcavallo.org/. It is not working to generate HTML code without a link so I added a default one becouse the link functionality is not needed in my software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my last attempt before I give up or go mad (or both).

#### TestHtmlIndent.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

class TestHtmlIndent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw =
            "<html><head></head><body><div>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 20px\">akamaitechnologies.com</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 17px\">amazonaws.com</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 18px\">cotendo.net</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 24px\">facebook.com</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 17px\">google.ch</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 25px\">heise.de</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 16px\">ip-plus.net</a>" +
            "<a href=\"http://a.b\" style=\"font-size: 21px\">ligatus.com</a>" +
            "</div></body></html>";
        String style =
            "<style type='text/css'>" +
            "body {width: 600px;}" +
            ".cloudLink {text-decoration: none; color: #0174DF; " +
            "font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;}" +
            "</style>";
        raw = raw.replace("<head></head>", "<head>" +  style + "</head>");
        String space4 = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp";
        String space20 = space4 + space4 + space4 + space4 + space4;
        final String processed1 = raw.replace(
            "<a ", space20 + "<a class='cloudLink' ");

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, processed1);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: thx for your effort! padding on the div tag is working and gives me the hope that there is a way to accomplish a solution to my problem(I assume that if padding is implemented, margin is aswell). But I need margin between each of the links becouse there is no line breack between them. Big sorry if this was not clear. The whole thing is supposed to be a tag cloud.

Comment: Good idea! It looks like the padding of the wrapped divs works. But the each div with a link in it is on a new line now even if there would be enough space to have several divs next to each other per line. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It seems block level elements lose their padding when made into `display: inline` elements.  So that is me out of ideas for the moment.  :(

Comment: Let's say it is the brute force version =) Thx very much for your effort! This works for me. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You can add left and right margins to inline-elements (not so top and bottom margins)
Maybe your `styleSheet.addRule` fails?

What's the generated HTML Code? It tried the code below and it works. Maybe the margin gets overridden in some stylesheet. Did you check with firebug?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>a {font : arial; text-decoration: none; color: #0174DF; margin-left: 50px}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 50.24324324324324px">akamaitechnologies.com</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 17.37837837837838px">amazonaws.com</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 18.243243243243242px">cotendo.net</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 24.08108108108108px">facebook.com</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 17.594594594594597px">google.ch</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 55.0px">heise.de</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 16.08108108108108px">ip-plus.net</a>
        <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch" style="font-size: 21.054054054054056px">ligatus.com</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: styleSheet.addRule is "working". Changes to the color or text decoration apply to the output. But I will try to add the style rules directly into the html as you did with `<style></style>`.

Comment: then your margin must get overidden. Try adding "!important" after margin-left: 50px

Comment: the String looks now like `<html><head><style>a {font : arial; text-decoration: none; color: #0174DF; text-align: left; margin-left: 50px !important;}</style></head><body>...` i don't use the `styleSheet` of HtmlEditorKid anymore. All the style settings are working except the `margin-left`

Comment: that's odd. There must be some small error. BTW: You should use font-family:arial instead of font:arial