# Java: Text not wrapping in JFrame dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using a JFrame to present a message box with some text and 2 buttons. How do I get the text to wrap automatically based on the size of the box?

Here's my current code:

```
        dialogFrame = new JFrame();

        JButton newButton = new JButton("New");
        newButton.addActionListener(new newUploadAction());

        JButton resumeButton = new JButton("Resume");
        resumeButton.addActionListener(new resumeUploadAction());

        //dialogFrame.setUndecorated(true);

        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel addPanel2 = new JPanel();

        addPanel.add(newButton);
        addPanel.add(resumeButton);

        String text = "<html><p>A previous control file exists for this file. ";
        text += "Would you like to initiate a new transfer or resume the previous one?</p></html>";

        JLabel testLabel = new JLabel(text);

        //testLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1)); 

        addPanel2.add(testLabel);


        Container content = dialogFrame.getContentPane();


        //content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); 

        content.add(addPanel2);
        content.add(addPanel);


        dialogFrame.setSize(200,200);
        dialogFrame.setVisible(true);
        dialogFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I read somewhere that calling

```
  testLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
```

would cause the wrapping behavior I want, but that just resulted in the text not showing up at all.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420742/make-a-jlabel-wrap-its-text-by-setting-a-max-width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the text in a `JTextArea` and call `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on the `JTextArea`. If you want it to look more JLabel-ish, then just change the color settings of the `JTextArea` to your liking.

**EDIT 1**

Also another thing that could work: consider having the holding `JPanel` use a `BorderLayout`:

```
JPanel addPanel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //!! added BorderLayout
```

So that the `JLabel` added will fill the `addPanel2`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `JTextArea` solution and cool name, but another option would be to embed `HTML`.

Comment: @mre: The problem with `HTML` is that you need to specify the location of line breaks whereas *I believe* that the OP wants lines that wrap depending on the size of the GUI.

Comment: @HFOE: "The problem with HTML is that you need to specify the location of line breaks.."  Not with a smattering of CSS.  E.G. `<body style='width: 200px;'>`.  The output in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805328/java-html-in-swing-link-margin-not-working/5806181#5806181) is restricted to 600px width.

Comment: you're completely right, but I suppose you could use the work around @Andrew Thompson mentioned.