# Render HTML to display in a Java application

Tags: java, webkit, swt, html-rendering

I'm interested in displaying HTML text (using CSS) in a Java app. What options do I have?

Although I don't use SWT in my app, I see SWT provides an interface to a WebKit browser on all platforms. Is there a way I can use SWT's WebKit integration to ask it to render the text in an image that I can reuse?

Comment: @Andrew I have `<span>`s and `<div>`s with `style=" /* CSS */ "` attributes.

Comment: I was about to add another comment, but instead to decided to add an answer. ..See answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Swing HTML support

Swing components(1) will render HTML 3.2 and basic styles. It might be a viable option if you control the HTML.

### HTML

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373621/loading-images-from-jars-for-swing-html/6373907#6373907) for 2 quick examples of using images in HTML

### Direct from a Jar file

[image: JEditorPane displaying Jar'd HTML]

### Using relative references

[image: Image referenced from base]

### CSS

For examples of styling HTML in Swing components using CSS, see the answers to:

#### [Java: HTML in Swing, link margin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805328/java-html-in-swing-link-margin-not-working/5806181#5806181)

[image: Link Cloud]

#### [Word Wrap in `JButtons`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766175/word-wrap-in-jbuttons/5767825#5767825)

[image: Word wrap @ 160px][image: Word wrap @ 200px]

### Caveat

1. More specifically, *some* Swing components support HTML.  The 1st screen shot is from a `JEditorPane`, the rest use a `JLabel`.  Many components use a `JLabel` as the default rendering component, such as tool tips, & default list & table renderers. `JButton` supports HTML partly.  It will render incorrectly for a disabled button.  `JTextPane` (styled text) also supports HTML, but `JTextArea` & `JTextField` (plain text) do not.

### See Also

For more information see [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

[Native Swing](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) allows to use an SWT Browser in Java Swing applications and to mix it with Swing widgets. It supports both WebKit and Xulrunner on several platforms (as well as IE on Windows). Make sure to have a libwebkit or libxulrunner that is compatible with the latest SWT implementation as described in the [SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux)
The browser engine to use is controlled by an NSOption passed to JWebBrowser:

```
JWebBrowser geckoWebView = new JWebBrowser(JWebBrowser.useXULRunnerRuntime());
JWebBrowser webkitWebView = new JWebBrowser(JWebBrowser.useWebkitRuntime());
```